# Moodle 3.10 Event Handler Custom Plugin is triggering when Exam Submitted

Tags: php, moodle

I have added a custom plugin to create one json file in moodle 3.10, I have used \mod_quiz\event\attempt_submitted event to trigger the event in the custom plugin. II also registerd that event in db/events.php.

Currently when a user submit the quiz, I can see that event in Site Adminstrator -> Reports -> Logs

But that event trigger in the custom plugin is not triggering.

Here is the code structure for that custom plugin.

classes/event_handler.php

```
<?php
namespace local_attempt_submission_plugin\classes;

defined('MOODLE_INTERNAL') || die();

class event_handler {
    public static function handle_attempt_submitted(\mod_quiz\event\attempt_submitted $event) {
        // Gather data from the event object (e.g., user, quiz, scores, etc.)
        $user = $event->get_record_snapshot('user', $event->userid);
        $quiz = $event->get_record_snapshot('quiz', $event->contextinstanceid);
        $score = $event->grade;

        // Prepare data to write to the JSON file
        $data = array(
            'user_id' => $user->id,
            'quiz_id' => $quiz->id,
            'score' => $score,
            // Add any other relevant data here
        );

        // Convert data to JSON format
        $json_data = json_encode($data);

        // Define the path and filename for the JSON file
        $json_file_path = 'C:\sample\response.json';

        // Write data to the JSON file
        file_put_contents($json_file_path, $json_data);
    }
}
```

I have registered this event in db/events.php

```
 <?php
    $observers = array(
        array(
            'eventname' => '\mod_quiz\event\attempt_submitted',
            'callback' => '\local_attempt_submission_plugin\classes\event_handler::handle_attempt_submitted',
        ),
    );
```

This is my lib file

```
defined('MOODLE_INTERNAL') || die();
 
 function local_attempt_submission_plugin_extend_navigation(global_navigation $navigation) {
     global $USER;
     
     // Check if the current user is a teacher (capability to create files)
     if (has_capability('mod/quiz:manage', context_system::instance(), $USER->id)) {
         $url = new moodle_url('/local/attempt_submission_plugin/create_file/index.php');
         $node = navigation_node::create('Create File', $url, navigation_node::TYPE_CUSTOM, null, null, new pix_icon('t/backup', 'Create File'));
         $navigation->add_node($node);
     }
 }
```

I am expecting this code will create response.json in sample folder when the exam is submitted.

Help me to fix the code! Please

Comment: If the custom plugin is already installed, then you will probably need to bump the  number in `local_attempt_submission_plugin\version.php`

Comment: it is already added in the version.php

Comment: Yeah, if you increment the number so the plugin is updated, then the event might work

Comment: I have updated it already

Comment: Okay, at glance your code looks good to me. So my next step would be to put a breakpoint in your event handler code, then trigger the event and step through in your favourite IDE. You might need to install xdebug if you haven't already https://xdebug.org/

Comment: Or add unit tests https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Testing#Unit_tests